# how we can remove the # sine in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

how we can remove the # sine and use the locationprovider this is my code we use this but its not working

```
 <base href="/" />

var app = angular.module('quizApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
  angular.module('quizApp').config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 

           var routes = [{
                  url: '/home',
                  template: 'templates/quiz.html',
                  controller: 'quizCtrl'
              }];

          routes.forEach(function (r, index) {
              $routeProvider.when(r.url, { templateUrl: r.template, controller: r.controller });
          }); 
          $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
              $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      }]);
```

Comment: _but its not working_ means? any console errors?

Comment: You can use angular ui-router instead instead of ngRoute.

Comment: Refer to this [**post**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)